# Y axis values not aligned with axis lines if I set min and max value on y axis in line chart

Tags: android, kotlin, linechart

If I  set the min and max value for y Axis in line chart. The Gridlines of Both YAxis are unaligned by their values. I am using MPAndroidChart library. below is my code to set min and max value for y Axis.[image]

```
    val yAxis: YAxis = chart.axisLeft
    yAxis.axisMinimum=min
    yAxis.axisMaximum=max
```

I want to display y axis values aligned with x axis lines.